# can we used same key in AES or DES

Tags: java, security, aes, des

As i am using client server communication, where i used same key (shared key) between client and server. but problem arise key is change every execution so i want to fixed it. is their any solution to take fixed key using AES/DES on both side.

```
private static void setUp() throws Exception {
    key = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm).generateKey();
    System.out.println(key);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    System.out.println(cipher);
}
```

Comment: There are countless ways to use the same key. If it is pre-shared, then you must have some way to read it from some storage location. Here are some I can think of: configuration file, encrypted configuration file, in code, retrieved from a third party trusted server through TLS/SSH, etc. Either way, you store it in some way like binary data or encoded string (e.g. hex, base64). There are simply too many variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec` as a `Key`. This allows you to give the key as a byte array.